# Обьясните по поводу сервлетов

Tags: java, servlet

Здравствуйте,на данный момент изучаю сервлеты, и собственно создал сервлет,в нем html теги,там я сделал кнопочку,которая при нажатии должна открывать html документ в папке WEB-INF,обьясните пожалуйста,почему при созданном сервлете не открывается html документ?до сервлета html документ открывался,как создал сервлет нет.

Answer (score 1):

Я не эксперт в сервлетах, но, насколько осведомлён, WEB-INF - папка сервлета, к которой запрещён доступ со стороны пользователя, т.е. к её содержимому может обращаться только сервер.